# jQuery How to Expand AND Collapse Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-animate

Target functionality is to expand AND collapse the form field by clicking on the image as seen in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/phamousphil/4jw42kza/).  Currently I have expand working using `.animate()`, however after much fiddling I can't find a way to collapse.

My question is twofold:
1. How can I implement the opposite animation to collapse the form when clicking on the image?
2. (bonus) How can I use `.animate()` to leverage CSS `visibility` to fully hide the form when collapsed?  My attempt to implement this failed.

Code below:

HTML:

```
<input class='header-search-box' type='text' id='search-string' name='search-string'>

 <img src='    http://findicons.com/files/icons/974/glyphish/18/magnifying_glass.png' class='magnifying-glass' />
```

CSS:

```
.header-search-box {

}

.header-search-box {
    width: 0px;
}

.magnifying-glass {

}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  var mglass = $('.magnifying-glass');
  var form = $('.header-search-box');
  mglass.click(function(){
    form.animate({'width': '100px'}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    var mglass = $('.magnifying-glass');
    var form = $('.header-search-box');
    mglass.click(function () {
        if (form.is(':hidden')) form.show()
        form.animate({
            'width': form.width() == 100 ? '0px' : '100px'
        }, 'slow', function () {
            if (form.width() == 0) form.hide()
        });
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4jw42kza/2/)**

Comment: A few modifications, but this is my final product if anyone would like to see in the future: http://jsfiddle.net/phamousphil/4jw42kza/

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve it by toggling a 'expanded' class and using CSS3 to handle the animation (and visibility):

CSS:

```
.header-search-box {
   visibility: hidden;
   width: 0;
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.expanded {
   visibility: visible;
   width: 100px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
   var mglass = $('.magnifying-glass');
   var form = $('.header-search-box');

   mglass.click(function(){
      form.toggleClass('expanded');
   });

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8rLmokp1/